Can Seals Eat Sushi?
In a story I'm writing at one point a kid's sitting on the docks and feeding the Seals sushi, and I'm wandering if that's actually possible, and what kinds of sushi they can actually eat or if it would make them sick. If no, then I plan on editing the world of my book so that seals are capable of eating sushi. (What I mean is like making it so some seals live near rice fields and eat rice and farmers need to put up barriers to keep them out and stuff like that.) If seals can eat sushi already I don't need to make those sorts of changes to make it fit.

To the person who VTCd for not being worldbuilding, this question is the difference between a world in which a kid feeds seals and one in which a kid attempts to poison seals.

@MontyWild How does the OP's world change based on this question? From what I see OP is asking about what will happen in an already built world that looks exactly like our own. Writing a disclaimer, suggesting the reader doesn't do something in real life, does not change any aspect of the world.

I was asking because, If seals can't eat sushi in real life, I was going to make some changes to the behaviour of the seals in my world so they can eat rice and such.

@sphennings Sometimes the world being built is changed by the answer, rather than having been changed in the question.  Just because you can't see what's changing in the question doesn't mean that changes aren't being contemplated by the OP.

Hello @Anonymous. Let me help clarify the problem. Taken as written, this isn't a worldbuilding question. It's a [biology.se] question. We have a real world question policy that I once supported, but it's been abused for so long that I no longer support it. Had you explained that you would need to modify the nature of seals in your world based on the answer to the question, that would have been sufficient to stop the debate because it's no longer "just" a real world question. Note, though...

... that IMO it's not enough to tell people that you're writing a story or that you're building a world (I know this isn't what you did or what you would have done), you need to explain why a rule of your world depends on the answer and how that varies from the real world. Cheers.

And sorry, I was tired when I wrote the original entry.

If you are going to have seals in your world be capable of eating sushi then why are you asking us what is possible in the real world? In your world you have already decided that the answer to the question is yes.

Even if someone fed sushi containing cooked rice to seals, there is a big step between that and a seal making the connection that the plants growing in fields is eatable. Rice in fields has stalks, hulls, and bran which are removed in the harvesting and milling process. http://www.knowledgebank.irri.org/step-by-step-production/postharvest/milling

@sphennings I would have to change seal behavior and diets to fit sushi being edible if the answer was no, but if the answer was yes I wouldn't have to do that.

As in, say on the off chance that I get famous, some idiot from PETA reads my book and claims I'm promoting animal cruelty or some such thing. If seals can indeed eat sushi, then I can just show proof of that. But if they can't, then in the book I'm going to make a point of seals being able to in that world, such as the rice thing I mentioned above, or perhaps something better.

Japanese and mild Americanized sushis should be fine
In a typical roll of sushi, most of the vegetable mass (the rice) is cooked.  This breaks down the cellulose that makes plants difficult for carnivores to digest.  We already do the exact same thing in a lot of dog and cat foods where we use cooked rice as a filler ingredient.  If a dog or cat can survive off such food for every meal for years on end, then the occasional bit of cooked rice is not going to harm a seal either.
As for other possible non-meat ingredients, these won't exactly be "good" for the seal, but they won't poison it either.  When I started making sushi for myself, I was often surprised at just how few actual vegetables go into a sushi roll.  Even Americanized sushi is mostly rice because the area of the outside of a circle (where the rice goes) is so much greater than the area of the inside of the circle (where the meat and raw veggies go).  A medium sized cucumber, carrot, or avocado can go into making about 60-200 pieces of sushi.  So, for a girl to share a few pieces of sushi means she's only actually feeding the seal a couple of teaspoons of raw vegetables, tops.  Other common vegetables like radish, lettuce, cabbage, and ginger should be fine too. None of these vegetables are particularly digestible, but they are not in high enough of a volume to be particularly harmful and none should be poisonous either*.
Over-all sushi is not an ideal food for seals, but it's no worse than feeding a human a cookie**.
Avoid Spicy or Saucy Rolls
The one thing you need to be careful about is spicy rolls or the kinds with sauces drizzled on top.  These often contain lime, mustard, chili, garlic, and/or onion which are all toxic to most non-human animals.  A bit of soy sauce should be fine, but would probably mask the smell of the fish and make the seal unwilling to eat it.

*Reports of Avocados being poisonous to pets are often taken out of context.  It is the pit of the Avocado that can poison your dog.  They can eat the flesh of an entire Avocado (the part we put in sushi) without any noticeable side effects.
**Toxicity issues aside, you should technically never feed a wild animal.
This encourages the animal to expect humans to feed it which can result in behaviors that are dangerous to both humans and the animal you are feeding.

If we consider some recipes for sushi, and have a look at the ingredients:
https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/24228/sushi-roll/
https://www.taste.com.au/recipes/sushi-2/0d57247f-03a6-434d-b26b-071b91614d41
We have just two ingredients that would be suitable for feeding to seals, namely salmon or imitation crab meat, which is just fish by another name.
However, seals are carnivores, and their digestive system would not be adapted to all the vegetable matter in sushi, which is mostly rice.  It's not toxic, but it isn't really digestable to carnivores, so it might cause bloating.
However, the most concerning ingredient in sushi would be the avocado.  Avocados contain persin, which is toxic to many animals, including dogs and cats.  As seals don't regularly eat avocado, I wouldn't expect them to be any less affected by avocado than other carnivores.
So, if the OP's character is feeding sushi to seals, at the very least have the kid throw just the salmon or fake crab to the seals, and have the kid eat the rest... it isn't suitable for seals' consumption.

I am not sure the Japanese version of sushi contains avocado. Like the Italian pizza doesn't contain pineapple.

@L.Dutch Every recipe I've found for sushi so far (3 recipes) have all included avocado.  However, sushi without avocado is possible, but I've already stated the likely effect of rice... if the seals would even be interested.

Originally, Japanese sushi was just rice and and fish, and later included seaweed.  Most of the other stuff you find in sushi tends to be American additions.  That said, American sushi can now be found in most Japanese sushi restaurants and vice-versa; so, it's a lot more important to consider both no matter where your setting is since it's not 1970 any more.

With this in mind, it would be possible to replace the sushi for sashimi when feeding seals, and still keep the "kid feeding seals with chopsticks" imagery.

If you try to feed the seal sashimi, it will probably just eat the fish off the top. Because American sushi has the meat on the inside, it's more likely to eat it whole.

Having eaten sushi in Japan, I can report that I've never once seen avocado in Japanese sushi. Full disclaimer, though: I'm much more a fan of Nigiri Sushi (raw fish over rice) than I am Temaki Sushi (rice rolls).

@Nosajimiki As far as I'm aware, sashimi is just slices of fish, without any rice. You may be thinking about nigiri?

@JBH Temaki is specifically the cone-form of sushi. If I'm not mistaken, the term for the generic "rolled with rice" forms of sushi is "makizushi".

@MontyWild Sushi is a very generic food, like "sandwhich". It isn't because cheese is a popular sandwhich ingredient that all sandwhiches have cheese. Avocado on sushi is very common on certain parts of the world, but very uncommon in others. Japan rarely uses it. On Brazil it is usually an offered option, but not that popular.

Source: I'm a hobbyst (and novice!) sushiman.

@Mermaker Lol, freaking America.  Apparently Nigiri is often mislabeled as Sashimi at the restaurants around here.  Thanks for the fact check... that said, I don't think true Sashimi would be considered Sushi at all because it is not made with rice.  It is the rice, and not the things you put on/in it that makes it sushi.

@Nosajimiki that's why I said to use Sashimi instead of sushi =P. You're correct that sashimi isn't actually sushi, despite a bunch of people considering it so!

@Nosajimiki Also, sushi terminology is difficult. On Brazil, Gunkan is a popular name for Jow sushi, where actual Gunkan has nothing to do with it. We also have the strange low-carb variant of sushis were there isn't no rice at all - is fish, rolled up with more fish instead of rice, topped with fish. It's like an edible fish frankenstein. And it is friggen delicious.

@Mermaker All that roll needs to be crammed up the backside of a turducken.

Not sure about turducken, but it has been used in Brazil as a pizza topping and a lasagna filling.

If you bloat as a seal, do you float at the sea-ceiling, the back is sealed, your fate is sealed, you float above the fishes, like a buoy, unable to dive, until there is a fart to save your life?
